# How to get Radio button values through submit form via Extjs BoxComponent?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am having some difficulties in making a form submission via a boxcomponent. I am using the boxComponent as I have customized button image, and strangely the transparency only works with boxComponent.

Basically the idea is that when I click on my boxComponent button, it will do 2 things:

1. Submit 2 radio button values and 1 combobox value via HTTP POST to sendstock.php
2. On successful submission, it will then proceed to the next page

Here's what I have got for the boxComponent:

```
var bc_button = new Ext.BoxComponent({
        autoEl: {
            tag: 'img',
            src: 'next_button.gif'
        },
        style: 'cursor: pointer;',
        listeners: {
            enable: function(c) {
                c.getEl().on('click', function() {
                myformpanel.getForm().getEl().dom.action = 'sendstock.php';
                myformpanel.getForm().getEl().dom.method = 'POST';
                myformpanel.getForm().submit({
                    success:function() {
                        window.location.replace("toNextPage.php");
                    }
                });

            });
            }

        }
});
```

Here is my question, the results is as per below:

```
comboxbox = 3, 
radiobtn1 = on
radiobtn2 = on
```

What I required is the value of the radiobtn1 and radiobtn2 to be submitted, should provide me with `Available` or `NoStock`, instead of `on`.

Also, is this the correct way to send users to the next page upon successful submission?

Thanks!

Comment: Lets see the markup for the form you are trying to submit.

Comment: Also, why don't you just let the form submit on its own, and have `sendstock.php` issue a redirect header to `toNextPage.php`, no JavaScript needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set the `inputValue` config property on your radio buttons.

```
var rad = new Ext.form.Radio({ name: 'something', inputValue: 'purple'});
```

The `inputValue` value should then be sent on form post instead of 'on'.